Can't see SQL Server option in Informatica Cloud when creating "Target Connection"
I'm new to Informatica so please bear with me.
I'm trying to create a simple job in Informatica Cloud that copies data from one SQL Server DB to another.
In "Connect Source" I created the connection to my Azure SQL Database; the connection was successful. For testing purposes, I want to copy the data to a table, also in Azure SQL Database. If not possible, then to a SQL Server database.
When I try to create the "Target Connection", I only see 5 options and none are for SQL Server or Azure SQL Database.
What am I doing wrong?


I'm not sure how did you get to this window. Are you creating a mapping? Or Synchronizatino Task? I don't recognize which product and option we're talking about here. I need a hit.
Apart from that: you should be able to create connection in IICS Administrator . Connections.
It is possible that Azure SQL Server as a target license is not available. But that's just a guess.
